# Coffeescript class instance in callback through classes

Tags: oop, coffeescript, instance

When i run this code:

```
class Dog
    constructor: ()->
        @dog_name = "tulio"
        the_bird = new Bird()
        the_bird.bird_sing(@the_method)
        @say_name()

    the_method: ()->
        @dog_name = "james"

    say_name: ()->
        alert @dog_name


class Bird
    bird_sing: (callback)->
        callback()

the_dog = new Dog()
```

why the alert is sayng "tulio" instead of "james"?
Aparently the callback dont know about this(@)
how can i get "james" ?

Comment: `@dog_name` = `this.dog_name` or `the_dog.dog_name`. but `this` isn't bound to the context of `Dog`. So its not the same variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `the_method` is the callback it needs to be bound to the context of this:

http://jsfiddle.net/uaxrgrom/

```
the_method: ()=>
    @dog_name = "james"
```

alternatively it needs to be bound on the call

```
the_bird.bird_sing => @the_method(args...)
```